# Excess vertical space when using booktabs cmidrule in math align environment

Tags: align, rules, booktabs, vertical-spacing

I'm using booktabs cmidrule in a math align environment. It's working but it's producing too much vertical space. How can I reduce that vertical space.

Here's a simple demo

[image: cmidrule has excess vertical spacing]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  % dummy placeholder equations. highlight spacing
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\
  \cmidrule{1-2}
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to use `align` here?

Comment: I do want to align a list of equations. Someone else suggests `array` however `\tag{eq1}` doesn't seem to work with that. What else do you recommend?

Comment: I'd suggest the other other answer then as it allows you still use `\tag`s. You can also capture the horizontal coordinate of the widest elements within your `align` and then draw a rule to match the horizontal width of the construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way, I'm surprised that `\cmidrule` works *at all* outside of `tabular`-like and `array` environments. The fact the use of `\cmidrule` doesn't throw an immediate error message is not an indication that what you're doing can or should be expected to produce the result you're hoping to get.

If you must use `\cmidrule`, do typeset the equations in question in an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\texttt{array} approach
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.28} % emulate display-style math setting
\begin{array}{@{} R @{{}={}} L @{}}
  1 + 1 & 2 \\
  1 + 1 & 2 \\
  \cmidrule{1-2}
  2 + 2 & 4 \\
  2 + 2 & 4 
\end{array}
\]
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\texttt{align*} approach
\begin{align*}
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\
  \cmidrule{1-2}
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is excellent. Except `\tag{eq1}` doesn't work with array like it does with align. Is that another thread entirely? The spacing with array is perfect.

Comment: Also, if I may ask, how would a user know that cmidrule isn't supposed to work inside `align*` but is supposed to work inside of `array`?

Comment: @clay - The title of the user guide of the `booktabs` package is "Publication quality tables in LATEX", and the document goes on to mention `tabular`-like and `array` environments (which share a lot of code "under the hood") at great length; not a single example with a multi-line display math environment in the entire document, though. Please note that I did *not* claim that "`\cmidrule` isn't supposed to work inside `align*`"; instead, I expressed my surprise that it works *at all* (though rather imperfectly). You can still use `\tag` to associate a single equation number with the `array`.

Comment: @clay - If you need to find out how  number individual rows of an `array` environment, please post a new query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce vertical space in this example or in a similar case add negative space before, for example  with  `\\[-2ex]`

In addition to the excessive space you notice `booktabs` adds vertical space both sides of the `\cmidrule` so it is harder to correct.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  % dummy placeholder equations. highlight spacing
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\
  1 + 1 &= 2 \\[-1.5ex]
  \cline{1-2}
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
  2 + 2 &= 4 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: x]

Comment: Your write-up appears to suggest that the chief reason for the excessive amount of vertical whitespace padding shown in the OP's screenshot is the fact that `\cmidrule{1-2}` adds vertical space. That's not quite right, though, as your own code -- which uses `\cline{1-2}` instead of `\cmidrule{1-2}` -- demonstrates.

Comment: Right. I corrected my comment. Thank you for your feedback.